# Oracle sql populate null values from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with more than 40 millions of data. The issue is some of the columns are `NULL` and I have to populate these `NULL` value from the same table based on some rule.

example - table has four columns: `name`, `telephone`, `email` and `city`
 and data like below:

```
name    telephone   email          city
test    123                        delhi
test    123         xyz@test.com
```

Then as name and telephone in above rows are same, we can populate email in the first row using data from second row and similarly city in second row from first row. I have heard of `first_value` function, but is running quite slow. Is there any alternate?

Comment: You could always do a self join.  However you have to be sure that the matching records you get really do represent the same person.  You'll also have to be wary of getting more than one possible match.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the simplest is to use `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT name,
       telephone,
       FIRST_VALUE( email ) IGNORE NULLS
                            OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone ) AS email,
       FIRST_VALUE( city  ) IGNORE NULLS
                            OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone ) AS city
FROM   table_name;
```

you can also replace `FIRST_VALUE` with `MIN` or `MAX`.

or you can do something similar with `LAG()` and `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT name,
       telephone,
       COALESCE(
         email,
         LAG( email )  IGNORE NULLS
                       OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone
                              ORDER BY ROWNUM ),
         LEAD( email ) IGNORE NULLS
                       OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone
                              ORDER BY ROWNUM )
       ) AS email,
       COALESCE(
         email,
         LAG( city  ) IGNORE NULLS
                      OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone
                             ORDER BY ROWNUM ),
         LEAD( city ) IGNORE NULLS
                      OVER ( PARTITION BY name, telephone
                             ORDER BY ROWNUM )
       ) AS city
FROM   table_name;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I think it would not work if the column which is populated is not previous or next